# Firebase using useSyncExternalStore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm setting up a simple React + Firestore project and most guides uses useEffect to listen for firestore changes.

After reading [you might not need an effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) I started looking for another way. I ended up trying to use the react hook useSyncExternalStore and it works. I do however not se the benefit from just using a hook with useEffect? is this even the correct way?

```
const useFirestore = () => {
  const store = useSyncExternalStore(firebaseStore.subscribe, firebaseStore.getSnapshot);
  return store;
};

let data: string;
const firebaseStore = {
  getSnapshot: () => {
    return data;
  },
  subscribe: (callback: () => void) => {
    const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "my-collection", "my-document"), (doc) => {
      data = doc.data().someData;
      callback();
    });
    return unsub;
  },
};
```

Second way I could do it is putting everything in a hook but not sure if it makes any difference?

```
const useFirestore = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const getSnapshot = () => {
    return data;
  };

  const subscribe = (callback: () => void) => {
    const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "my-collection", "my-document"), (doc) => {
      setData(doc.data().someData);
      callback();
    });
    return unsub;
  };

  const store = useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSnapshot);
  return store;
};
```